The centers of the circles passing through the vertices of 3 triangles lie on the same line
Today while using the GeoGebra app I discovered a nice geometric feature

We have a triangle (blue), and we drew the axes of its sides (black lines), and we assigned the points of intersection of those six axes with the sides of the triangle, which differ from the midpoints, and we made them the vertices of two triangles (green and red), where in one of the triangles we take points clockwise, and in the other we take points counterclockwise.  Clockwise, now if we draw the circles surrounding the three triangles, their centers will lie on one line (orange line)
Is the property new or already known, if it is already known please point to a reference that mentions it, also I have no idea how we can prove this If someone has an idea about a suitable approach to proof please do so

By "axis" of a side, do you mean the perpendicular bisector? If so, then I have confirmed your result with a bit of computer-aided coordinate bashing. ... I don't know if this result is "known".

Yes, this is what I mean, and thank you for your work on solving it. I was expecting a geometric model for the solution. I did not think of the model that deals with the coordinate system. @Blue

Really nice property! In fact, we can prove a stronger claim. Let $O$ be the circumcentre, and let $XP,YQ,ZR$ be the perpendicular bisectors of $BC, CA, AB$, where $X \in AC, Y \in AB, Z \in BC$, and $P \in AB, Q \in BC, R \in AC$.


Claim: Perform an inversion about the crcumcircle $\odot(ABC)$. Then $X \leftrightarrow P, Y \leftrightarrow Q, Z \leftrightarrow R$. 
Proof: Let $P'$ be the image of $P$ under this inversion. Then $P'$ must lie on circle $\odot (AOB)$ (as $A,B$ are preserved under the inversion, and the line $AB$ is inverted to circle $\odot (AOB)$). Moreover, $P'$ also lies on line $OP = PX$. Thus, it suffices to show $BOXA$ are concyclic. But this is true since it can be easily verified that $\measuredangle OXC = \measuredangle OBA = 90^\circ - \angle C$. $\blacksquare$
Alternatively, one could also have observed that $\measuredangle OAC = \measuredangle APX$, so $OA$ is tangent the circle $\odot (AXP)$, whence $R^2 = OA^2 = OX \cdot OP$.

Note that this implies that the green and red circles in the OP's diagram ($\odot(XYZ)$ and $\odot(PQR)$) map to each other under this inversion, hence the line joining their centres must pass through $O$ (though the centres do not map to each other). 

This also implies another interesting property, which is visible in the OP's diagram : these three circles are coaxal. This is because the intersections of the circumcircle with $\odot(XYZ)$ must map to themselves, but their images lie on $\odot(PQR)$, so the three circles are coaxal.

Thank you for this wonderful answer, I never imagined that it would be possible to present such a beautiful perception about my property @DS
